# 'dayjs' should be listed in the project's dependencies lint error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, lint

I added day.js (because moment.js is deprecated) into my project and after running lint, I got this error:

```
'dayjs' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S dayjs' to add it
```

I don't use npm, but yarn. Tried to google for it, but no luck. Anyone can help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this chunk of code in your eslintrc.js

```
 settings: {
 'import/core-modules': ['dayjs'],
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer is one way to do it i.e.

```
settings: {
 'import/core-modules': ['dayjs'],
}
```

Or it could be `dayjs` could be installed as a `devDependencies` in package.json, installing it as a `dependencies` will solve it too.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what package manager you're using `npm` or `yarn` but first you've to uninstall `dayjs` from your `devDependencies`. Or it maybe installed as a `peerDependency`. And then just do `npm install dayjs` or `yarn add dayjs` which will install it as in `dependencies` of your package.json